# Assign an array literal to a variable in Liquid Template

Tags: jekyll, liquid

The only way i know to create an array from my liquid template is:

```
{% assign my_array = "one|two|three" | split: "|" %}
```

Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 31):

**Frontmatter**

This is a good workaround, add to the top of your file:

```
---
my_array:
  - one
  - two
  - three
---
```

then use it as:

```
{{ page.my_array }}
```

Analogous for site wide `site.data.my_array` on the `_config` or under `_data/some_file.yml`.

**Jekyll 3 update for layouts**

If the frontmatter is that of a layout, you need to use:

```
{{ layout.style }}
```

instead. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37418818/895245

Comment: Another option is to create a file named "_data/my_array.yml" and put inside the contents: "  - one
  - two
  - three". Then, it is accessible via site.data.my_array as you said.

Comment: why create it in template directly is prohibited?

Comment: @Adi don't know exactly. In general Liquid is crippled by design to allow running untrusted templates.

Answer (score 8):

> Is there any other way to do it?

Nope, your `split` filter is the way to do it.

Comment: correct. You must use `split`. Shopify docs on liquid array: https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/basics/types#arrays

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it by first using [`capture`](http://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/variable/#capture) as a friendly way to assign newline-separated values to a variable and then converting that variable to an array with [`assign`](http://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/variable/#assign) and a few filters:

```
{% capture my_array %}
one
two
three
{% endcapture %}

{% assign my_array = my_array | strip | newline_to_br | strip_newlines | split: "<br />" %}
```

The filters do the following:

1. [`strip`](http://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/strip/) removes the leading whitespace before `one` and the trailing whitespace after `three`.
2. [`newline_to_br`](http://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/newline_to_br/) replaces newlines with `<br />` tags.
3. [`strip_newlines`](http://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/strip_newlines/) removes possible extraneous newlines.
4. [`split`](http://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/split/) converts the string into an array, using `<br />` as a separator.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the array in the page frontmatter like:

```
---
my_array:
  - one
  - two
  - three
---
```

I have tested that you could simply write it like so:

```
---
my_array: [one,two,three]
my_prime: [5,7,11,13,17,19]
---
```

Both of `{{ page.my_array }}` and `{{ page.my_prime }}` will  output correctly.