# Can you use Jekyll layout variables in pages?

Tags: jekyll

In a Jekyll layout, default.html, you initialize a variable

`{% assign relative_path = "../../" %}`

Inside a page using default layout, this variable is empty though.
How can you use inside pages variables set in layout?

This is the opposite of
[Can you use Jekyll page variables in a layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950152/can-you-use-jekyll-page-variables-in-a-layout)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some research in Jekyll code, it seems that you cannot access layout variables from a page or post. The only information about layout a page can see is the layout's name `{{ page.layout }}`.

Then you can use this to store some layout related variables in _config.yml and get them from any post/page using the `{{ page.layout }}` variable.

#### _config.yml

```
layoutVars:
    default:
        relative_path: "../../"
    post:
        relative_path: "an other path"
    page:
        relative_path: "hello world"
```

#### use in a page or post

```
{% assign pagePath = site.layoutVars[page.layout].relative_path %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two possibilities.

1. Store your variable in the layouts yaml-header, e.g.:
   ---
   variable  : value
   ---
2. Have a look at [jekylls front matter defaults](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#front-matter-defaults). You can declare variables depending on the type of posts/documents and the folder the posts are stored in.

I'm not if this is what you are looking for, but i hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks astark! David clarified